# request a web service from laravel that returns a json object

Tags: json, laravel-4

I have this Url : https://ipfind.co/?ip=188.225.179.138&auth=dde7cf52-2294-47e3-adb2-1e559099527e

when I request it from browser it gives me this response:

```
{"ip_address":"188.225.179.138","country":"Palestinian Territory, Occupied","country_code":"PS","continent":"Asia","continent_code":"AS","city":"Ramallah","county":null,"region":null,"region_code":null,"timezone":"GMT+2","owner":"COOLNET NEW COMMUNICATION PROVIDER","longitude":35.2,"latitude":31.9}
```

how can I invoke this url from laravel?
note that I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipfind.co/?ip=188.225.179.138&auth=dde7cf52-2294-47e3-adb2-1e559099527e'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec(); 
curl_close($ch); 
dd($data);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Curl you shall do this Easy 5 steps

**Step 1**

Initiate the Curl `$cSession = curl_init();`

**Step 2**

Define the Curl Url

```
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://ipfind.co/?ip=188.225.179.138&auth=dde7cf52-2294-47e3-adb2-1e559099527e");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

**Step 3**

Execute the Curl

```
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
```

**Step 4**

Close the Curl Connection

```
curl_close($cSession);
```

**Step 5**

Print the Result

```
echo $result;
```

**Putting all together**

```
<?php
$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://ipfind.co/?ip=188.225.179.138&auth=dde7cf52-2294-47e3-adb2-1e559099527e");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP package for getting an IP address for IP Find that you can install with composer here that works great with Laravel.
https://github.com/tenfef/ipfind-php/